# I have an app with user interface on a virtual server. After each restart of the server (even when I am not logged in) my app should run autmatically

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-server-2019, app-startup

I have an app (programmed in C#) on a common virtual server that is reading data from the production machines in our plant. As it is a new concept there is a user interface where I have to check whether everything is OK and make sometimes some settings. After each restart of the server (even when I am not logged in) my app should run automatically. I have tried everything like:

a) In Task Manager run the app on startup automatically.

b) Startup directory of Windows Server 2019

c) registry settings for automatic Startup.

When I am logged in on the server and restart the server with logging in again there is no problem.
But when I am not logged in, and the server is restarted out of my info, for example by our IT Department for some patches or updates on sundays mostly, then my app is not starting automatically.

I know that the best way should be that I convert my app to a service. But due to the mandatory user interface that I have to keep, I cannot do it. What should I do in this case?

Comment: what kind of app is it? what kind of user interface?

Comment: It is a desktop form app written in C# by myself.